# Python(Cython) multiprocessing does not show error message

Tags: python, error-handling, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a code that that is using multiprocessing and pipes to send data from one process to another. A few hours ago when I modified my program I just saw the program running without errors, but not running correctly. Turned out the program just stalled at some point, where ValueErrors should occur, but nothing showed up.

If I use a try block to print out the error I can see that there was an error, but it does not show up on the screen (using pycharm). Tried it directly from the console, but same effect. There are some errors that show up, but for example indexing errors, not matching unpacking errors from a function result, numpy array not matching data etc.

Now I tried to find from what point it stops working and it is when I spawn a process(inside a process) with multiprocessing.Process.
I raised ValueError every line and right after I start

```
def spawn_socket_child():
    child, parent = Pipe()
    x = Process(target=start_kline_ticker_server, args=[child])
    raise IOError
    x.start()
    return parent, x

def spawn_socket_child():
    child, parent = Pipe()
    x = Process(target=start_kline_ticker_server, args=[child])
    x.start()
    raise IOError
    return parent, x
```

The first code works as expected, it throws the error and stops, but the second does not throw the error and does not exit the program since the main process is also running.

What could go wrong? I used the same methods on a different code and it worked just fine.
I just want to see errors again ="(

edit:
Changed Process to Thread and it works as expected again. Might as well keep it as a thread, hopefully it wont be a bottleneck, but I am still curious why Process disables error handling.

Comment: Did you setup logging in child processes? You have to do it separately. Why do you use `Pipe()` if you use `multiprocessing` module?

Comment: I will look into that later, i thought that the child process inherits it from the parent, so it should not be a problem. A child process inherits and works just fine, than the child creates a child and both child loses logging. Does not make sense to me.

Comment: Is there anything better? As far as i know there is pipe, queue and shared memory that works for multiprocessing. I had problems with queue. Empty, so i quickly moved to pipe and it works as I wanted so I stayed with it. Did not look into shared memory tho.

Comment: Standard use of `multiprocessing` is Queue, the module has very similar to `threading` module API.  `multiprocessing.Queue` is high level wrapper around `Pipes`. From my experience you have to define logging in child process.